# PineScript V.3 - fill conditional area coloring not working anymore

Tags: python, plot, colors, pine-script, fill

i have a conditional color fill not visible anymore, if you can help :)

```
line1=sx(0,1,N)+sx(0,2,N)+sx(0,3,N)
line2=0
p1 = plot(line1, transp=0)
p2 = plot(line2)
fill(p1, p2, color = line1>line2 ? white : black)
```

[Normal condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsUd0.png)
It should look like that (changing color depending of oscillator above or below 0)
But it doesn't work anymore since this morning and in the TV tree it's not visible as well.

[Bug since this morning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RSa8.png) How it looks like now with background no visible on the tree.

Comment: What type of error are you getting from console ?
The error you're saying is not reproducible without further info

Comment: No error. The code was working fine for the last 2 years. As you can see on the second screen shot, the plot() is visible but not the fill() anymore in the tree.  You need the full code? thx for your help :)

Comment: Yes, I will need to look into the code

Comment: May i send it to your email?

Comment: Sure, send it to spamaps@yahoo.com